# Product Review In Virto Commerce

Tags: review, virtocommerce

The product review section is seen in the official document (https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2userguide/merchandise-management/products-catalog), but not in the latest source code (https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-platform). Is the part displayed on the official website from another version?

Answer (score 2):

VirtoCommers platform has a modularity architecture. Each domain-specific functionality such as PIM *(Product information management)*  presented as standalone modules which can be installed into the platform in runtime. So, the platform solution does not contain code modules.

The catalog module is located in this  repository https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-module-catalog